# Changing the From address on emails from root

Tags: linux, email, gnu

When we get sent emails from cron jobs etc., they tend to have a From address like "root ".  Unfortunately, in Outlook, this only shows up as "root", which makes distinguishing between very similar emails from different machines quite tricky.

How can I change the From address on these emails so it's something like "foo.bar.example.com root "?

Comment: That would depend on what you use to send the emails.

Comment: Could be configurable in Outlook to show the full email address, check the relevant options dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name used is root's "full name" from the password database.  Change it with `chfn`:

```
chfn -f "root at foo.bar" root
```